# Does index data count against the free tier data quota in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) has [a quota of 1 GiB/day in the free tier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota). Does data in indexes count against that quota? I know that [indexes have their own limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes), but here I'm just concerned about their actual data usage.

An example: Let's assume I have 900 MB data (documents & collections) in Firestore. I also have many indexes that take up 200 MB on the storage medium. Now do these indexes now push me over the limit of 1 GiB/day for data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit includes the size of any indexes.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#storage-size):

> You are charged for the amount of data that you store in Cloud
>   Firestore, including storage overhead. The amount of overhead includes
>   metadata, automatic indexes, and composite indexes.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!